# Live server refreshing every second without changes in code file

Tags: visual-studio-code, reload, page-refresh, liveserver

When I'm using Live Server extension in VS Code, my browser is refreshing every second, even though I do not make nor save any changes in my code file.

Why is that happening and how to solve this problem?

Can anybody help me? :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: same happen to me, vscode win 10 x64, if I press save multiple times in short time, "reload" message is continuously send to live server extension in chrome, causing chrome reload in loop

Comment: I proposed that this be closed as a dup of [How to make live-server stop refreshing when nothing changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45576692/how-to-make-live-server-stop-refreshing-when-nothing-changed) and then merge them together into one Q&A.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. The issue was my (unrelated) script was running in background and writing to a file in the same directory. Live server detected these changes and sent the "reload" request to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue recently as well, and I spoke with a couple of people while testing various browsers.

We figured out that the issue was there was too much loaded into VSCode and it was looking through every single project/written code.

I closed VSCode down and then opened my repo for the particular project in terminal. I then used `code .` which opens VSCode, it opened only that specific repo/folders and then tried using Live server which worked perfectly with *no refreshes* happening.